# Getting data from three tables. Should I join them?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three tables I'm trying to use.

Author      (AuthorID, Lname, Fname)

Book Author (ISBN, AuthorID)

Books       (ISBN, Title)

Need to display it like this:

```
 AUTH LNAME     FNAME     TITLE
 ---- -----------------------------------------------
 S101 Smith     Roger     TRAVELING TO FRANCE         
 S101 Smith     Roger     HOW TO BAKE A CAKE
 J101 Wilson    Kenny     ADVENTURES OF THE MAN              
 P101 Peters    Lemon     SCIENCE AND MATH 
 S101 Fogo      Baker     SCIENCE AND MATH
```

The closest I can is this:

```
 SELECT authorid, title
 FROM bookauthor, books
 WHERE book author.isbn = books.isbn
```

Which gives me:

```
 AUTH TITLE                        
 ---- ------------------------------
 S101 TRAVELING TO FRANCE          
 S101 HOW TO BAKE A CAKE         
 J101 ADVENTURES OF THE MAN             
 P101 SCIENCE AND MATH
 S101 SCIENCE AND MATH
```

But that leaves out the first and last name, which I'm trying to include.

I looked at other questions regarding joining tables but I can't seem to apply it to my script.  Beginner at Oracle SQL so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could do...    select author id, Lname, Fname , title from author, book author,books where author.author id=booksauthor.authorid and booksauthor. ISBN=booksauthor.isbn

Comment: I am not sure but try this `SELECT authorid, lname, fname, title
 FROM author, books join bookauthor
 WHERE bookauthor.isbn = books.isbn and author.authorid = bookauthor.authorid`

Comment: Do you know about SQL JOIN? If not study it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do...

```
select author id, Lname, Fname , title from author, book author,books 
where author.author id = booksauthor.authorid 
and booksauthor.ISBN = booksauthor.isbn
```